# AngularUI Bootstrap Popover Not Working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Why isn't this popover working?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXAKj7Nvx3WMf1IRM5VH?p=preview)

```
<body>
<div class="flexbox margin-top">
  <div class="flexible"></div>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" popover-template="'template.html'" popover-placement="left">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html" >
<div>
  <textarea>Some text, some text, some text</textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-sm">Update</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

When the button clicked I want it to show the popover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with the code added in the question but I have found two issues in the posted [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXAKj7Nvx3WMf1IRM5VH?p=preview).

- *ui.bootstrap* module was not initialized

  ```
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  ```
- UI Bootstrap templates file was not included

  ```
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
  ```

This is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFV2jXfjHJMQwezqkKxs?p=preview) of your code.

Comment: :D I don't know how I didn't notice this. Thank you. Btw, do you know why the popover flickers when button clicked. I see it at the left top corner of the page for a very short moment. Then it goes to where it should be.

Comment: No, it seems that would need further investigation. It's happening because the popup is shown before it's position is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had a `bower.json` as follows

```
"angular-bootstrap":"0.13.1"
<other references in between to make two versions not visually obvious> 
"angular-ui-bootstrap":"1.1.2"
```

I tricked myself into thinking I had the latest bootstrap reference through the `1.1.2` line and didn't notice the old `0.13.1` which the web app was actually using.

ie: My web app was referencing the old version but I thought I was referencing the new version.

Removing the `angular-ui-bootstrap` bower package and fixing the version on `angular-bootstrap` made everything work.

The other final gotcha was using single quotes when specifying the inline template - ie: `uib-popover-template="'mytemplate'"`

Comment: Single quotes was my issue. Thank you!